# Skip cron job for a few hours

Tags: linux, cron

I was wondering if it was possible to tell cron to not execute any cron jobs for a couple hours ?

Comment: _not execute any cron jobs for a couple hours_ Is this about the whole system or only for particular user? Do you want to be repetitive or just one time? ... What is your problem actually?

Comment: Basically I just want to skip all the cron jobs for the next 24 hours for the system or for a user since I only have one user that is executing the jobs.

Comment: Yes; comment them out ... then in 24 hours, put them back ;) (Seriously, no, cron doesn't have a way to do that).

Comment: Stop the crond service and then restart it when you need it if you want all jobs stopped (/etc/init.d/crond stop|start  or similar for your system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shannonman mentioned, you can just stop the service and start it again when required.

#### Stop cron service

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
```

#### Start cron service

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
```

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-start-restart-cron/)